# C# Display unicode text in the caption of a message box

Tags: c#, unicode

C# 2005.

My application supports 2 langauges English and Thai.

However, in my message box for the caption it will display question marks i.e. ???????????? when I have to display Thai langauge.

The message box string text is ok. That displays ok. However, its just the caption that is having a problem.

Do I need to enable unicode in the messages boxes somehow?

Many thanks,

Comment: How does the code that displays the message box look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MessageBox caption have no problems with unicode characters. My guess (without having seen any code) is that the string for the caption has gone through some processing that does not support unicode.

Have you tried to display a MessageBox with hard-coded Thai text in the caption? If that shows OK you should follow the caption string backwards in your code and determine where it gets "de-unicodified".

Comment: Good answer! I like the way you logically deduced the problem.

Comment: Hello, I have directly added the thai language to the caption of the message box. MessageBox.Show(CATWinSIP_MsgStrings.languageFeatures, "ออกจากโปรแกรม"); However, I am still getting the question marks. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Does your windows settings use the same font for the window titles and text in message boxes? Can you show thai characters in a regular window caption?

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. I am using a skinning engine and I don't think it supports unicode. I have tried with and without the skins. The ones without the skins work, and the ones that have it don't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may install and use a font which supports desire characters. Not all fonts support all characters. the [] box character is the fonts representation of 'unsupported'

The textbox might be using MS Sans Serif by default, so change it to Arial or "Mangal" Arail uniocde.

arial support and mangal support most of lanuage charcters. if want check whethere the fonts are preinstalled, you may paste your  unicode code in "wordpad" or cheack using type run box "charmap"

Comment: They indicate that the message box string text is ok but the caption is not.  It's unlikely to be a font issue.